# Undo effects of included indentfirst

Tags: indentation

I'm using the [`hausarbeit-jura`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hausarbeit-jura?lang=en) class. This class unfortunately loads the `indentfirst` package which wreaks havoc by indenting every paragraph after a heading.

How can I get back to the LaTeX default behavior? Is there a way to override/undo what `indentfirst` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reinstate the definition of `\@afterindentfalse` that `indentfirst` makes equivalent to `\@afterindenttrue`.

```
\documentclass{article} % or whatever
\usepackage{indentfirst} % emulate the class loading indentfirst

\makeatletter
\def\@afterindentfalse{\let\if@afterindent\iffalse}
\@afterindentfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

This won't be indented.

This instead will.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!